# Logarithm of the exponent, including the transition from negative to positive

Tags: linear-transformations, logarithms, exponential-function

$ln(e^{\beta \cdot t})=\beta \cdot t$

$ln(e^{-\beta \cdot t+c})=-\beta \cdot t + c$

And what if:

$ln((-1-2)e^{-\beta \cdot t}+2)=???$

Comment: The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function, hence the first two equalities. However, the logarithm is not a linear function, so you will not be able to simplify in a similar fashion. What do you expect as a result?

Comment: @laura_b
maybe something like this:

$ln((-1-2)e^{-\beta \cdot t}+2) \sim a \cdot (t-b) + c$